# libc error with UWSGI for Django, UWSGI fails on site load

Tags: django, linux, uwsgi, libc

I am receiving a segmentation fault error in UWSGI that seems to be related to libc.so.6 in my linux system. I have no idea where to even start with this error.

The error happened after pushing code, but did not disappear after re-pushing the older code. We have 2 servers running this code, but only one is receiving this error.

The error is as follows:

```
Fri Sep 29 14:34:25 2023 - DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 57544) died, killed by signal 11 :( trying respawn ...
Fri Sep 29 14:34:25 2023 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 57759)
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - !!! uWSGI process 57545 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - !!! uWSGI process 57545 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - !!! uWSGI process 57545 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - !!! uWSGI process 57545 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - *** backtrace of 57545 ***
website.com(uwsgi_backtrace+0x35) [0x560449e94825]
website.com(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x560449e94bd3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33060) [0x7ffad1d63060]
*** end of backtrace ***
Fri Sep 29 14:34:47 2023 - *** backtrace of 57545 ***
website.com(uwsgi_backtrace+0x35) [0x560449e94825]
website.com(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x560449e94bd3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33060) [0x7ffad1d63060]
*** end of backtrace ***
```

I have reinstalled libc6, but it did nothing to solve the issue. I have reviewed configuration of UWSGI multiple times, but nothing has changed. There are no issues listed in the django log.

Any ideas as to where we should be looking?